# Lost Indian passport (cancelled one); I have a green card

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, paperwork, lost-documents, us-permanent-residents

I am an Indian citizen and permanent resident of the United States. I had two passports since my last name changed because of marriage, now I have lost my old passport but I do have my new passport and green card, I am traveling to India in two weeks; what should I do?

Comment: Why would you think you need your old passport?  Does your green card show your former name?

Comment: No, passport and GC has the same name

Comment: Could it be you had an important VISA in the old passport?

Answer (score 5):

One does not generally need old passports when traveling.  You have everything you need to travel between India and the US.  To leave and enter the US, you need nothing more than your valid green card.  To enter and leave India, you need nothing more than your valid Indian passport.

> what should I do?

Bring both documents with you and enjoy your trip.

If the green card shows your former name, that is, your name before you were married, then you can bring a copy of your marriage certificate as proof of your name change.

Comment: Do I need to file police report?

Comment: @KomalTrivedi whether you need to report a lost passport after cancellation is really a separate question to that of the documents you need for a trip between the US and India.  The main reason for reporting the loss or theft of a passport is to prevent its fraudulent use by someone else, but that reason is less important if the passport has been cancelled.  I don't see any questions about that on this site; perhaps you should ask one. You might also see what the Indian consulate has to say about it, since different countries can have different rules for their passports.

Comment: Ahh - could be the OP is dealing with a NAME CHANGE issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your current passport to enter/exit India, and your green card to re-enter the US.

Your old passport is irrelevant.